# MySQL Query to find customers who have ordered two specific products

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm having trouble coming up with a query that will find all customers who have purchased both PROD1 and PROD2.

Here's a pseudo-query that kind of looks like what I want to do: (obviously this wouldn't work)

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) 
  FROM TRANSACTIONS 
 WHERE product_id = 'prod1' 
   AND product_id = 'prod2'
```

So basically I'm trying to get a count of the number of distinct userids that have a transaction in the `transactions` table for both product_id '`prod1`' and '`prod2`'. Each transaction is stored in a row in the `transactions` table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I do this type of query in the following way:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.userid) AS user_count
  FROM TRANSACTIONS t1
  JOIN TRANSACTIONS t2 USING (userid)
 WHERE t1.product_id = 'prod1' 
   AND t2.product_id = 'prod2';
```

The `GROUP BY` solution [shown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676863/mysql-query-to-find-customers-who-have-ordered-two-specific-products/1676905#1676905) by @najmeddine also produces the answer you want, but it doesn't perform as well on MySQL.  MySQL has a hard time optimizing `GROUP BY` queries.

You should try both queries, analyzing the optimization with [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html), and also run some tests and time the results given the volume of data in your database.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT userid
  FROM TRANSACTIONS
 WHERE product_id in ('prod1', 'prod2')
GROUP BY userid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

(Added new options below using the additional information provided by the user)

Try

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE 
 EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Purchases WHERE ProductID = 'PROD1' AND CustID = Customers.CustID)
 AND
 EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Purchases WHERE ProductID = 'PROD2' AND CustID = Customers.CustID)
```

Or

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE 
 CustID IN (SELECT CustID FROM Purchases WHERE ProductID = 'PROD1')
 AND
 CustID IN (SELECT CustID FROM Purchases WHERE ProductID = 'PROD2')
```

Or

```
SELECT UserID FROM Transactions WHERE ProductID = 'PROD1'
 AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Transactions WHERE UserID = T1.UserID 
  AND ProductID = 'PROD2')
```

Or

```
SELECT UserID FROM Transactions WHERE ProductID = 'PROD1'
 AND UserID IN (SELECT UserID FROM Transactions WHERE ProductID = 'PROD2')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an Access answer based on the infamous Northwind sample db. You should be abe to translate that in mySql quite easily.

```
SELECT o.CustomerID, Sum([ProductID]='Prod1') AS Expr1, Sum([productid]='Prod1') AS Expr2
FROM Orders AS o INNER JOIN [Order Details] AS d ON o.OrderID = d.OrderID
GROUP BY o.CustomerID
HAVING (((Sum([ProductID]='Prod1'))<>0) AND ((Sum([productid]='Prod1'))<>0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userId)
FROM(
  SELECT userId
  FROM transactions
  WHERE product = 'PROD1'
  INTERSECT
  SELECT userId
  FROM transactions
  WHERE product = 'PROD2');
```

The query creates two intermediate tables, one which contains userId of customer who bought PROD1 and another identical table for those who bought PROD2.
The intersection operator returns a table which contains only rows found in both previous tables, i.e those who bought both products.

Answer (score 0):

Example for sakila db:

```
SELECT R.customer_id, GROUP_CONCAT(I.film_id) 
FROM sakila.rental R 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN sakila.inventory I ON R.inventory_id = I.inventory_id 
WHERE I.film_id IN (22,44) GROUP BY R.customer_id HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```