# what t-sql query would select customers with two specific products

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, combinations

I have a products table with custid and prodid.

I need to query the table to determine how many customers have a specific product combination:

- at least 1 product number 1
- at least 1 product in (2, 3, 4, 5)

And then I need to be able to list the customers in that category.

This question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676863/mysql-query-to-find-customers-who-have-ordered-two-specific-products) but when I tried the recommended solution I got error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'USING'.

Code:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT t1.custid) AS user_count
FROM 
    custrate t1
JOIN 
    custrate t2 USING (custid)
WHERE 
    t1.rgid = 333 
    AND t2.rgid in (321, 325, 329, 345, 360, 364)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you have a `USING` statement in the wrong place.  Show your attempt?

Comment: added it in above example

Comment: That USING is MySQL syntax, you need to follow TSQL syntax for joins: `FROM Production.Product AS p
INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod
ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID`

Comment: unfortunately I am unable to translate your example to my situation.  Here is my attempt which returned invalid object name on custrate.t1 and custrate.t2  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t1.custid) AS user_count
  FROM custrate.t1 as p
  INNER JOIN custrate.t2 AS sod on p.custid = sod.custid
 WHERE t1.rgid = 333 
   AND t2.rgid in (321, 325, 329, 345, 360, 364)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's go through this logically.  With less experience, my first instinct would have been to join to products with the specific criteria.  The problem is I'd end up with multiple records, so I'd need to aggregate down to a customer:

```
Select c.CustomerId
From Customer c
Join Product p on p.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
Where p.ProductId in (2, 3, 4, 5)
or p.ProductId = 1
```

Obviously this is wrong, as worse case scenario it gives us 5 records for a particular customer's joining to up to 5 matching products. If the goal is to get a single record if only BOTH criteria are met, we have to think about how I can "look across records".  There are three common approaches to "looking across records":

1. A subquery, either in the select, or in a where criteria using something like a `in` or `exists` clause, or occasionally as a nested join.
2. An aggregate query.  This sometimes requires a little creativity and problem solving.
3. A window function such as `MAX() OVER (PARTITION BY...)`

Possibly combined with the above would be `CASE WHEN` conditionals.

If you learn all of the above techniques, you will have a much larger mental toolbelt to begin to creatively solve these problems.  This answer is a bit broad to try and show examples of all of these, so I'll just show one solving your problem.

**EXISTS Subquery**

A subquery with `EXISTS` checks to see that at least one record is returned from a subquery, and the `EXISTS` returns true if any record is found.  Because the results are not actually used, and we only care if there is at least one record, it doesn't matter what is returned in the `select` of the subquery so we just return `1`:

```
Select c.CustomerId
From Customer c
Join Product p on p.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
Where p.ProductId = 1
```

The above alone returns no more than one record, and only if the customer has a related Product with ID = 1.  The below adds the additional criteria to eliminate records where there isn't at least one record of one of the other products existing:

```
Select c.CustomerId
From Customer c
Join Product p on p.CustomerId = c.CustomerId
Where p.ProductId = 1
  AND EXISTS
   (Select 1 From Product p2
    Where p2.ProductId in (2, 3, 4, 5)
      AND p2.CustomerId = c.CustomerId )
```

**This is the final solution.** Note it's important we only find related records in the subquery.  To accomplish this it's pretty common to have one or more criteria from the outer query matched with the inner query. In this case we have `c.CustomerID` from the outer query and `p2.CustomerId` to narrow down the results of the inner query.

Updated for self join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.CustomerId
  FROM Products p1
  JOIN Products p2 on p1.CustomerId = p2.CustomerId
 WHERE p1.ProductId = 1 
   AND p2.ProductId in (2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: I keep getting invalid object name on Product ... we are talking about a single table right?  There are not two tables (customer and product).

Comment: @XiVix In that case I've updated the question to add a query for a self join.  In your original question you said "I have a products table" but your error indicates you do not have a table named "products".  I assume your are capable of swapping out tables names to match your specific schema.

Comment: That worked.  I thought you were thinking two tables but I could not be sure because your query is so advanced.  My original question did state a single table, but I can't pick on you for missing that because you are such an SQL genius.  Thanks.  And yes I am able to swap out names.