# SQL: how to select customers who have ordered multiple items

Tags: mysql

here is some sample data:

```
ID Item 

1 A    
1 A 
1 B 
2 A 
2 A    
3 A 
3 A 
3 A
```

Question: Im trying to write code so that the only records that are selected are those of customer with ID 1 (ie a customer that has both product A and B). So results should look like this:

```
1 A    
1 A    
1 B
```

I've tried a lot of different things, but I am stuck. I tried self-join, but it doesnt produce what I want:

```
SELECT a.id, a.item
FROM table1 a Join table1 b on a.id=b.id
WHERE upper(a.item) = 'A'
AND upper(b.item) = 'B';
```

This will give me the right customer (ie customer 1) but it doesnt pull all 3 records. It just gives 1 row.

the closest similar question is 
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676863/mysql-query-to-find-customers-who-have-ordered-two-specific-products)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use your query as subselect to get the pid and then output all the pids rows. Like this:

```
SELECT id, item 
  FROM table1 
 WHERE id IN (SELECT a.id
                FROM table1 a 
                JOIN table1 b 
                  ON a.id=b.id
               WHERE UPPER(a.item) = 'A'
                 AND UPPER(b.item) = 'B')
```

Comment: Both RealCheeseLord and Jameson the dog have correct answers...how do I accept both?

Comment: @sqlfiddler You can only accept one answer. When there are multiple correct answers I personally accept the one which gives full explanation or if both are of same quality I personally accept the one being posted earlier. But you decide.

Answer (score 1):

since you want to see which users match a certain condition and the fetch everything about those users - you need a nested query:

```
SELECT id,item FROM table1 WHERE id IN(
    SELECT a.id
    FROM table1 a Join table1 b on a.id=b.id
    WHERE upper(a.item) = 'A'
    AND upper(b.item) = 'B'
)
```

I took your working query, and used it in a `WHERE` clause for a more generic query - should do the trick for you

Comment: great! happy to help :) 
feel free to accept answer

Comment: thanks...I tried. but both RealCheeseLord and you have correct answers...how do I accept both?

Comment: You can't but I upvoted so jameson get's some Points :)

Comment: oh well I'll take it :-)

Comment: I have a follow up question: Would this solution be extendable to more than 2 items? So, in a case where a customer had bought items A, B, C, and D, would you have to do 4 self-joins? and add two more where conditions for C and D? thanks!

Answer (score -2):

is it this what you are looking for? or may be I didn't understand your question.

```
SELECT a.pid, a.mname
FROM meds a 
WHERE a.pid = 1
```